# Gather rows that go along with a new column from VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

SampleSheet.xlsx - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ugha8sjvgrpi5w7/SampleSheet.xlsx?dl=0

This is a small, generic version of what I am really working with.  What would be my "A" column is extremely large and "B" is a selection of the larger column.  Columns "C" through "E" are data that goes along with each person (note only the people in "B" have this data.  In column "G" I have a VLOOKUP to see what names in "B" have a match in "A".  The question is how can I automatically pull the data in "C-E" that the matches have.  For example, when doing the VLOOKUP, "austin" will have the row "c1;c2;c3" after it automatically.  I understand this may not be possible with the VLOOKUP I did to get the matched names.

I want to be able to create a table with the a1,a2,a3, etc data with only the names that have a match in "A".

For example, what I want to end up with is a table like this: [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYpSY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this as a Macro and run if you are familiar with Excel VBA.

Variables to Consider here, you can change them according to your requirements :

- Uses Activesheet so you must use the Macro while the sheet with data is active
- Uses fix column numbers, 
  Long data is in Column A, 
  Data to Find is in Columns B to E
  Output starts from Column J

---

```
Dim result, lastrow1, lastrow2, lastrow
lastrow1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Y = 1 To lastrow1
result = Application.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Y),ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A16"), 1, False)
If Not IsError(result) Then
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ActiveSheet.Range("J" & lastrow) = result
ActiveSheet.Range("K" & lastrow) = Application.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Range("J" & lastrow), ActiveSheet.Range("B1:E" & lastrow2), 2, False)
ActiveSheet.Range("L" & lastrow) = Application.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Range("J" & lastrow), ActiveSheet.Range("B1:E" & lastrow2), 3, False)
ActiveSheet.Range("M" & lastrow) = Application.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Range("J" & lastrow), ActiveSheet.Range("B1:E" & lastrow2), 4, False)
End If
Next Y
```

Comment: I get an error when I run this: "Invalid outside procedure". I am not real familiar with VBA, I am not sure how to fix this.  I only have one module running.

Comment: In your module there must be a code block between Sub ......() and End Sub where ..... is the Macro name. This runs a block of code which is a Macro in Excel VBA. So to run the code it must be between a Sub ().... and End Sub. The ... is the Macro name it may be the macro that you are  currently working on or you might record it as new Macro by naming it Sub () MyNewMacro after paste the code and to the end add one more line End Sub. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Wonderful.  Thank you.